# Cordova - truncate file proxy not found

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to truncate `FileEntry` content, but am getting this error in cordova.js (@989:9) - `Error: exec proxy not found for :: File :: truncate` when trying to do anything related to truncating (`fileWriter.truncate(0)`), either after or before `seek`. The FileEntry / FileWriter exists and I'm fine to write to it.

I'm using Cordova 6.1.1

---

Per request, some code (this exists within a file class):

```
this.__write__ = function(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    console.log("Attempting to write", dataObj);

    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            fileWriter.write(dataObj);

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
                console.log("Successfully written to "+self.filename, dataObj);

                if (params.onwrite)
                    params.onwrite.apply(self)
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                throw new Error("Failed to write to "+self.filename, e.toString());
            };

            // If data object is not passed in,
            // create a new Blob instead.
            if (!dataObj)
                dataObj = new Blob([''], { type: 'text/plain' });
        }

        fileWriter.truncate(0);
    }, function(){
        throw new Error("Failed to create write on "+self.filename);
    });
}
```

If I add `truncate(0)` before `fileWriter.write(dataObj);` I get abovementioned error

Comment: Could you post more details to it like the sample code? Are you testing this on android marshmallow?

Comment: @Gandhi - I'm currently testing it on my pc, using `cordova run browser`, so as browser.

Comment: which version of file plugin are you using? As i could see similar issue which got fixed in file plugin version 4.1.0 Check this link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10023

Comment: @Gandhi 4.2.0. Just tested it on Chrome and it's indeed working as expected, but Firefox throws the error, so it might be a similar issue. Will report it as a bug and we'll see where it goes. Cheers!

Comment: oh Ok fine. So can i post previous comment as answer to this question so that we can close it?

Comment: @Gandhi - I'd rather wait for fix to this issue, but I can as well accept your answer and then put in the link to bug / solution in OP when it becomes available. Either way is fine, I guess :)

Comment: Have posted the answer so that it can be helpful for someone who is stuck with similar issue. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an issue similar to the [one](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10023) which got fixed in file plugin version 4.1.0 As per your input, it works fine in chrome as expected but not in firefox. Could possibly an issue with plugin. Please raise a bug as you suggested and lets hope for the best. Cheers.